# what kind of statement before for loop is possible in python

Tags: python

I see a code like this in python

```
x = [[0] * 2 for i in range(2)]
```

this results in an array of 2d array. x has a value of

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

My question is what kind of statement  can we put in front of the for loop? I don't quite understand how to use this. Is there a name for this kind of use in python? Is this a good practice(pythonic)?

Comment: you're looking for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Try doing it with a mutable object inside the list

Answer (score 3):

Any expression can be placed before the `for` in a **list comprehension**, although it is almost always one that relates to the name given between the `for` and the `in`.

Related are **generator expressions** (aka genexs), which do not include the square brackets. They yield each resultant item in turn rather than generating an entire list at once.

Answer (score 1):

That code uses the mutiplication operator with lists, for example `[0] * 3` produces as result `[0, 0, 0]`.

To create 3x3 matrix one may be tempted to use

```
M = [[0] * 3] * 3
```

but this wouldn't work as expected. The reason is that the result will look apparently correct when printed but it will behave strangely because the `*` operator simply places three times the **same row** in the outer list.

In other words after changing for example `M[0][1]` also `M[1][1]` will appear as modified, because `M[0]` and `M[1]` are indeed the same list object.

A solution is therefore to use instead

```
M = [[0] * num_cols for i in range(num_rows)]
```

because the `[<expr> for <var> in <iterable>]` generates a list evaluating `<expr>` for each iteration, thus producing a distinct list object each time.

You can use any Python expression in `<expr>`, in most cases it will be an expression that depends on `<var>`, but this is not required.